# Dynamic Javascript code is not working in Thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, java, spring, thymeleaf

I am making a project in Spring Boot with Thymeleaf. I want to add a dynamic popup to my project for this purpose I want to add some Javascript code to my project. But it is not working.

test.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <script src= "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
  <div class="popup" id="popup" onclick="openPopup()">
    <img src="tick.png" >
    <h2>Thank you!</h2>
    <p>Your details bla bla simple message.</p>
    <button type="button" onclick="closePopup()">OK</button>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

script.js :

```
let popup = document.getElementById("popup");
function openPopup() {
    popup.classList.add("open-popup");
}

function closePopup() {
    popup.classList.remove("open-popup");
}
```

style.css :

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #3c5077;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.btn {
    padding: 10px 60px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 500;
    border-radius: 30px;
}

.popup {
    width: 400px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.1);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 30px 30px;
    color: #333;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: transform 0.4s, top 0.4s;
}

.open-popup {
    visibility: visible;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}

.popup img {
    width: 100px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.popup h2 {
    font-size: 38px;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin: 30px 0 10px;
}

.popup button {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    background: #6fd649;
    color: #fff;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

When I open html file in view mode it is like this(popup is hidden in the beginning) : [image]
When I started the application it seems like : [image]

How can I solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, what does `openPopup` and `closePopup` does ? Can you add code for that as well ?

Comment: Hi, I have added css code also.

Comment: Please , check if [this](https://jsfiddle.net/268ogpjL/) works for you.

Comment: No it is not working. Here the problem for me is to running this on my Spring Boot application in Java. And I am using for HTML things Thymeleaf.